# SQL incorrect JOIN and condition compare value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

I'm doing these statements, and am off by getting the correct min and max range of values.

```
SELECT 
C.CourseId, 
C.GradeValue MinGradeValue,
isnull(min(m.GradeValue)-1,100) MAxGradeValue,
L.LetterGrade ,
L.[Description] 
    FROM CourseGrade C

    LEFT JOIN LetterGrades L
    ON C.LetterGradedId=L.LetterGradeId 

    LEFT JOIN CourseGrade m
    ON m.LetterGradedId=L.LetterGradeId  AND m.GradeValue > C.GradeValue

    GROUP BY
    C.CourseId, 
    C.GradeValue, L.LetterGrade ,
    L.[Description];
```

[image]

This is what the correct range should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last join needs to be on the CourseID:

```
SELECT 
    C.CourseId, 
    C.GradeValue MinGradeValue,
    isnull(min(m.GradeValue)-1,100) MAxGradeValue,
    L.LetterGrade ,
    L.[Description] 
FROM CourseGrade C

    LEFT JOIN LetterGrades L
        ON C.LetterGradedId=L.LetterGradeId 

    LEFT JOIN CourseGrade m
        ON m.CourseId=c.CourseId
        AND m.GradeValue > C.GradeValue

GROUP BY
    C.CourseId, 
    C.GradeValue, L.LetterGrade ,
    L.[Description];
```

Answer (score 0):

look at

```
  LEFT JOIN CourseGrade m
    ON m.LetterGradedId=L.LetterGradeId  AND m.GradeValue > C.GradeValue
```

first string
c.GradeValue=0
this condition is false

```
m.GradeValue > C.GradeValue
```

therefore you get null in min(m.GradeValue), your isnull return 100